# How do you group objects in array if they have the same key value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to create an array of grouped objects if the have one same key value pair.

For example, Ungrouped Array:

```js
let ugArray = [
   {name: 'jack', type: 'dog'},
   {name: 'brad', type: 'dog'},
   {name: 'ella', type: 'cat'},
   {name: 'lily', type: 'cat'},
   {name: 'rod', type: 'goat'},
]
```

and i want to group it by type so that the output will be:

```js
let groupedArray = [
   {dog: [
      {name: 'jack', type: 'dog'},
      {name: 'brad', type: 'dog'}
   ]},
   {cat: [
      {name: 'ella', type: 'cat'},
      {name: 'lily', type: 'cat'},
   ]},
   {goat: [
      {name: 'rod', type: 'goat'}
   ]}
]
```

Comment: what does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just use an object instead of an array of objects:

```js
let ugArray = [
   {name: 'jack', type: 'dog'},
   {name: 'brad', type: 'dog'},
   {name: 'ella', type: 'cat'},
   {name: 'lily', type: 'cat'},
   {name: 'rod', type: 'goat'},
];

let grouped = ugArray.reduce((result, obj) => {
  if (result[obj.type]) {
    result[obj.type].push(obj) 
  } else {
    result[obj.type] = [obj]
  }
  return result
}, {})

console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: Each of the group is a separate object in OP's expected output

Comment: I know, I was making a suggestion to simplify the grouping by using a single object